# Specify 'pip' version in requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, requirements.txt

I develop a Python/Django application, which runs from a virtual environment (created by `virtualenv`).

When the virtual environment is created, the global version of `pip` is copied to the newly created environment by default, which might be quite outdated (for example, version `1.5.4` from `python-pip` package on Ubuntu 14.04).

To avoid manual `pip` upgrades, it sounds like a good idea to pin the `pip` version in `requirements.txt` file, for instance by adding the following line:

`pip==8.1.2`

Specifying the `pip` version there will also allow to upgrade `pip` in all the managed application environments (local, dev, production) by changing the line in the requirements file.

Does this sound like a good practice? Is there anything that can go wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please note that `pip` version listed in `requirements.txt` is going to be installed along with other requirements. So all requirements are going to be installed by old version of `pip` and the version specified in `requirements.txt` will be available afterwards.

I always do:

```
virtualenv /path/to/my/desired/venv/
source /path/to/my/desired/venv/bin/activate
pip install -U pip
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Good point. Looks like it makes sense to do both, then: install the modern pip version right after creating the virtual environment, and specify it in requirements.txt for documentation/later-upgrades purposes.

Comment: I wouldn't specify it in requirements.txt - it's a false requirement in the first place. Is it really the case that your software won't install correctly with older pip? I really don't think so.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo new requirements file formats such as ~= are not backwards compatible so yes there are cases where our software won't install correctly with older pip

Answer (score 0):

What you experience is caused by an old version of `python-virtualenv` delivered with Ubuntu 14.04. You should remove the Ubuntu package and install via pip:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Then make sure you have the newest pip installed as well.

```
sudo pip install -U pip
```

And you should get that version installed in new virtual environments.

Comment: If `pip` was installed via `python-pip`, `sudo pip install -U pip` will not work. It will tell you:

`Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS`

Comment: Then, uninstall it via `apt-get`, get https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and `sudo python get-pip.py` or `sudo python3 get-pip.py`.